# A word that represents both getting on and/or off of something (in general)

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a single word or phrase that exists to represent the action of both getting on and/or off of something such as public transport in general?

I understand there are words like ingress/egress, embark/disembark, ascent/descent, board/deboard, etc. but these only represent one or the other.

Comment: Alight might fit but it's usually followed by the thing you should alight on, alight the train, the platform etc. Are you looking for a word that doesn't require that?

Comment: Something like “passenger numbers” or “passenger loadings” which represents one and the other.

Comment: You can take a bus or take the train from here to there (and possibly back again). Or go by air, when you can go by air.

Comment: I cannot imagine such a word, but I'll be delighted to learn it here. Any word I think of is linked to passing from and to. If you want to make it rough you might say, "I *landed* on the bus which took me along until I *landed* at 42nd St." I'm waiting for better.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to express the number of occasions on which someone moved from a platform or pavement to a train or bus and the number of occasions when someone did the opposite? If so 'transition' might work but you'd have to explain your use of it the first time you used it in your work.

Answer (score 1):

English has no specific word for "I inverted my state of possibly being on a vehicle."  You'd have to either use a specific word like "board" which means only on or off, or else you'd have to explain and set up a really specific unusual context where a reader could understand a very generic word like "changed" to mean what you want.

I could imagine a book trying to set up something like that, but it would be a literary device, and probably only used to talk about a character being really bored or numb so they don't pay attention to what they are doing.  Not a standard way of talking about it.